# Argument of type '{ name: ROUTE_NAME; props: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RouteLocationRaw'

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I'm using vue js and quasar as biblio , I'm trying to pass data between two screens after making routing so I'm passing it as props in router.push and make the call in onMounted method

This code is related to Admin.vue file:

```
    const EditWorkSetting = (data) => {
  router.push({
    name: ROUTE_NAME.HOME_NEWSETTINGS,
    params: data
  });
};
```

in the onmounted method:

```
 onMounted(() => {
  fetchCompanySettings({ pagination: pagination.value });
  const paramsData = route.params;
});
```

in the other hand I want to call the data in setting.vue file that I'm routing to (realted to ROUTE_NAME.HOME_NEWSETTINGS )
for script in settings.vue , it's simple like that :

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
import { reactive, ref } from "vue";
import http from "@/plugins/axios";
import { qSelectBase, INewSettingsForm } from "../../interfaces/pages/welcome";
import { ROUTE_NAME } from "@/router/Types";
import { Notify } from "quasar";

const step = ref(1);
const router = useRouter();

//other const decalarations
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Answer to the old Question: Argument of type '{ name: ROUTE_NAME; props: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RouteLocationRaw']

You're getting this error because in `router.push()` you're passing an object with `name` and `props` which are accepted in `Vue Router v3.x`.

But in `Vue Router v4.x` the type of `RouteLocationRaw` accepts `params` instead of `props`.

so you might as well try renaming `props` to `params` like this.

```js
const EditWorkSetting = (data) => {
  router.push({
    name: ROUTE_NAME.HOME_NEWSETTINGS,
    params: data
  });
};
```

and in the componenet where you're passing these params. You can access them like this.

```js
onMounted(() => {
  const paramsData = route.params;
});
```

Vue Router v4.x RouteLocation: https://router.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/RouteLocation.html

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks just I have a question , for the code in onMounted I make it in HOME_NEWSETTINGS component ? (the component that I'm routing to ) I'm getting this error :Property 'params' does not exist on type 'Router'

Comment: Did you import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'?
and before onMounted() function write const route = useRoute();

if this doesn't work then kindly show me the full code.

Comment: I've updated code in post, you can see it ^^

Comment: The issue you've stated before "Property 'params' does not exist on type 'Router'" doesn't seem to be occuring here. so what's the issue now then?

Comment: I just want to know how to display the data transferred from Admin.vue  to setting.vue

Comment: ok. let me add another answer to for this.

Answer (score 1):

**[Answer to Updated question: how to display data transferred to targeted Component]**

to display data in `setting.vue` where you've accessed `route.params`.
add following script in `setting.vue` `<script></script>` tags.

```js
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

export default {
  setup() {
    const paramsData = ref({});
    const router = useRoute();

    onMounted(() => {
      paramsData.value = router.params;
    });

    return {
      paramsData
    };
  },
};
```

then to display the `paramsData` in `<template></template>` tags.

```html
<div v-if="paramsData.rows">
  <div v-for="eachRow in receivedData.rows" :key="row.id">
    <!-- write the tags here accessing data with eachRow -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Noman , I really appreciate your effort , but what if my script is already have this form ? <script setup lang="ts"> import ... const ... </script> how can I change it to your answer ?  your can see the form of script in the posted question

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255448/discussion-between-nomanabid-and-mira we can make disc here